# pass a parseGeoPoint between activites

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-studio

I have a listview of coordinates when I click on on a view I want to send the value of coordinate to another activity (`getParseGeoPoint()`) 
,My problem is that I don't know what datatype I need to cast and then cast-back

```
      public class A
        {
        ....
        setContentView(R.layout.someLayout1);
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> parse=ParseQuery.getQuery("class");
        parse.whereEqualTo("someValue","someValue");
        parse. ...
         .
         .
       public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e){
       Intent I =null;
       I=putDataType("point", (someType) object.getParseGeoPoint)
}
```

class B:

```
     public class B{


        {...
         .
         .
         setContentView(R.layout.somelayout2);
         Intent i=getIntet();
         i=getDataTypeExtra("point");
      }
}
```

thanks for your time .

Answer (score 0):

Reading through this -
https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseGeoPoint.html
So you can pass double latitude and longitude between the two activities. In your activity receiving the intent you can make a parsegeopoint object like this-

```
 ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
 ParseObject object = new ParseObject("PlaceObject");
 object.put("location", point);
 object.save();
```